# Expandable Angular mat table throws Can't bind to 'cdkDetailRow' error

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I need help to solve this. I'm new to Angular programming.

I started to learn a new Angular Material component from an example.

I found this expandable mat table, but when I try to compile it this error shows:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'cdkDetailRow' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
1. If 'mat-row' is an Angular component and it has 'cdkDetailRow' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ader-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [ERROR ->][cdkDetailRow]="row" [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
"): ng:///AppModule/OrderDTComponent.html@37:90
Can't bind to 'cdkDetailRowTpl' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
1. If 'mat-row' is an Angular component and it has 'cdkDetailRowTpl' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row" [ERROR ->][cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
"): ng:///AppModule/OrderDTComponent.html@37:111
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2426)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20600)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26146)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26133)
    at compiler.js:26076
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26076)
    at compiler.js:25986
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2417)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25985)
```

Here's the app-module.ts code

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OrdersComponent } from './orders/orders.component';
import { OrderComponent } from './orders/order/order.component';
import { OrderItemsComponent } from './orders/order-items/order-items.component';
import { OrderService } from './shared/order.service';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular/main';
import {MatTableModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSortModule, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { ItemsComponent } from './items/items.component';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
import { ItemInsertComponent } from './items/item-insert/item-insert.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { OrderDTComponent } from './order-dt/order-dt.component';
import {CdkDetailRowDirective} from './order-dt/cdk-detail-row.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OrdersComponent,
    OrderComponent,
    OrderItemsComponent,
    ItemsComponent,
    ItemInsertComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    UserComponent,
    OrderDTComponent,
    CdkDetailRowDirective

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(), 
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    CdkDetailRowDirective


  ],
  entryComponents:[OrderItemsComponent,ItemInsertComponent],
  providers: [OrderService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here the directive.ts

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdkDetailRow]'
})

export class CdkDetailRowDirective {
  private row: any;
  private tRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  private opened: boolean;

  @HostBinding('class.expanded')
  get expended(): boolean {
    return this.opened;
  }

  @Input()
  set cdkDetailRow(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.row) {
      this.row = value;
      // this.render();
    }
  }

  @Input('cdkDetailRowTpl')
  set template(value: TemplateRef<any>) {
    if (value !== this.tRef) {
      this.tRef = value;
      // this.render();
    }
  }

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    this.toggle();
  }

  toggle(): void {
    if (this.opened) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
    } else {
      this.render();
    }
    this.opened = this.vcRef.length > 0;
  }

  private render(): void {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    if (this.tRef && this.row) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef, { $implicit: this.row });
    }
  }

}
```

and here's the code for app-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular7s';
}
```

Here's the link of the sample that I copied:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting?file=app%2Ftable-example.html

It would be nice if u guys can help.

Comment: How your app.module.ts looks like>

Comment: There is no error in your stackblitz example. Also in general, when you get such error, then it means the particular module in which the component/directive exists (here, there must be a module which contains cdkDetailRow)  has not been binded in your application

Comment: thanks for the fast respond, i already post the app.module.ts and the app-component.ts code, @PrashantPimpale,

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things you're not importing the correct materials into the project in the right places. Check [this link](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), particularly the section

> Step 3: Import the component modules.

Once you do everything in this section the error should disappear. In Angular, just importing in a component isn't enough, you will have to import in the correct module as well. If you are using the default build and have not added additional modules, the file will be app.module.ts.

I note in the Stackblitz this is done in the main.ts, which may have confused you.

The code in your module file should look something like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Noting now that you have done this, I have checked the [Angular Mat Table documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) and it appears as if the `cdkRowDetail` attribute is not supported, which is likely what's causing your error. You'll want to remove the `[cdkDetailRow]="row"` binding from your HTML, and also the `[cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl"` binding as well or you'll get a different error.

Also, you'll want to initialise all the variables in your TypeScript file app.component.ts. You should be able to copy the one in the stackblitz directly without issue but let me know if anything doesn't work with that.

If you need to use the custom behaviour from the stackblitz you'll need to copy the code from the directive, then `import {CdkDetailRowDirective} from './app/cdk-detail-row.directive';` in your app.module. You will then need to declare it in your declarations array in the same file.

You should not have CdkDetailRowDirective in your imports array, so your @NgModule should look like this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(), 
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    NgxPaginationModule
  ],
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the respond @Young Ninja , i already post the full code, i try to import to app.module.ts , but here's come the error : error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/tkhun/Desktop/Angular7s/src/app/order-dt/cdk-detail-row.directive"' has no exported member 'cdkDetailRow'.

Comment: Let me try this on my local computer and have a look for you make sure what I've told you is right. First thing though is to make sure you've run `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` as well...

Comment: Ok, I have replicated the issue on my machine and think I understand the cause of the problem. I notice the version in the stackblitz for @angular/material is 6.3.2. Can you confirm which version number shows in your package.json? Looking at the current Angular docs it seems like the property you are trying to access doesn't exist anymore (e.g. cdkDetailRow isn't a thing in the new Angular material table).

Comment: "@angular/material": "^7.3.2", here's is my angular material version

Comment: I've updated my answer above. I believe that removing the `[cdkDetailRow]="row"` binding from your HTML, and also the `[cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl"` will solve your issue. You'll also need to add the appropriate variables to your app.component.ts or you'll get more errors.

Comment: i already try to delete the [cdkDetailRow]="row" and [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl", yes there's no error , but the table can not drop down / expand , wat i want is the row can drop down while we clicked

Comment: Did you add the directive (cdk-detail-row.directive.ts)? That's where the custom property resides, so with hindsight it's no wonder it's not shown in the Angular documentation. You'll also probably need to `import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';` in app.module.ts and add this to your imports array

Comment: yes i generate the new class on the terminal , named it same as the file and copied all the code into it,

Comment: In which case you will need to import it into your app.module as you are not doing so at present: `import {CdkDetailRowDirective} from './app/cdk-detail-row.directive';`. You will then need to declare it in your declarations array in the same file.

Comment: hello YoungNinja, i already import the CdkDetailRowDirective in app.module.ts , here's come the error " Unexpected Directive imported by the module AppModule, please add @NgModule annotation,

Comment: hi taufan; please update your app.module.ts code. Currently it does not show a CdkDetailRowDirective import and you do not have a declarations array.

Comment: I'm at work at the moment but I'll take a look when I get home this evening. Please also post the contents of the directive.

Comment: is OK, u can post when u're at home, really appreciated YoungNinja, FYI : i already edited above with the directive code

Comment: Hi again taufan. At home now. The problem you have now is that you're adding CdkDetailRowDirective to your imports array as well as your declarations array. You should only have it in your declarations array. I have updated my answer.

Comment: hii Young Ninja, sorry for the late reply, thanks for the respond, i try to did about wat u suggested, but come into another error,